# Updating data in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem updating an existing row in my database. What I need to do is add a record to a field named "Time_Out". This field is on the same row as with the "Time_In", "username", and "date_added". The Time_In is working perfectly fine. This is the code I've used:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei'); 
$date_added = date ("Y-m-d");
$time_added = date ("h:i:s:a:");
$user = $_SESSION['xxxx']['xxxxx'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "test");
$save = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO time_logs (username, date_added, Time_In) VALUES('$user', '$date_added', '$time_added')");
if(!$con) {
    die('Could not connect to the database' . mysql_error());
    mysql_close($con);
}
else
    header("Location: etc.php");
```

For the Time_Out, I have removed the "INSERT INTO ..." line and changed it into:

```
$save = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = $time_added WHERE username = $user");
```

but the record in the Time_Out field in my database is still showing 0:00.
By the way, my date_added is set to Date and the Time_In and Time_Out is set to Time.

I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how to do this using PHP. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you echo "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = $time_added WHERE username = $user" what is it?

Comment: @WizKid I am sorry, I am new to MySQL and PHP. How do I exactly echo that line?

Comment: `echo "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = $time_added WHERE username = $user";`

Comment: It is showing the correct value of time and username.

Comment: do `mysql_query('...') or die(mysql_error());` and see if you get an error

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs, they don't mix. Change `die('Could not connect to the database' . mysql_error());
    mysql_close($con);` to => `die('Could not connect to the database' . mysqli_error());
    mysqli_close($con);`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` when in development.

Comment: Thank you for your reply guys, I'm just missing single quotes for the values. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Consider just using `NOW()` to insert/update your dates like `INSERT INTO time_logs (username, date_added, Time_In) VALUES('$user', NOW(), NOW())` and using appropriate MySQL date/datetime field types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing single quotes around your non-numeric data. Try:

```
$save = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = '$time_added' WHERE username = '$user'");
```

Comment: I can't believe I haven't tried that. It actually worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a few issues. First in this chunk you are using `mysqli_*` and `mysql_*` extensions mixed together when they should all be `mysqli_*`:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei'); 
$date_added = date ("Y-m-d");
$time_added = date ("h:i:s:a:");
$user = $_SESSION['xxxx']['xxxxx'];
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxx", "xxxx", "test");
$save = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO time_logs (username, date_added, Time_In) VALUES('$user', '$date_added', '$time_added');");
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect to the database' . mysqli_error($con));
    mysqli_close($con);
}
else
    header("Location: etc.php");
```

Specifically it was in your `if (!$con) {` check.  Look at the cleaned up example now. But also, your update does not have single quotes around string values:

```
$save = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = $time_added WHERE username = $user");
```

So it should be like this:

```
$save = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = '$time_added' WHERE username = '$user'");
```

But to make your life easier, you might want to reformat your queries like this:

```
$query = "UPDATE time_logs SET Time_Out = '" . $time_added . "' WHERE username = '" . $user . "';";
$save = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Note how I set the query in a separate string & then added concatenation to the string itself for the variables. This makes it easier to spot issues like this in text editors in my humble option. I also ended each of your queries with a semicolon (`;`) since that again makes it clearer to me that is the true end of the query statement.

Comment: I will surely apply this one to make my codes look less complicated. I have also replaced all the mysql to mysqli. Thank you for this tip and have a good day.

Comment: I would definitely do that after I have gained 15 reputations. I'm on 12 right now.